# python two lists object didn't act as usual

Tags: python, list

```
l=[1,2,3];
l2=l
l.append(4)
```

when the l append the 4, then the l2 will also have 4 since they are sharing the memory.
but how to explain the code below:

```
l=[1,2,3]
l2=l
l=[]
l.append(4)
```

this time the l2 will not have the same change as l anymore.
Is this have something deal with the deep theory of computer memory.

Comment: You reassigned `l` to a new empty list. Why would changing it effect `l2`?

Comment: When you do `l=[]`, you are referencing `l` to another list, not modifying the original list. You can do `l.clear()` or `l[:] = []` to modify the original.

Comment: If you did `l = "abc"`, would you expect that to affect `l2`? Why is `l = []` any different?

Comment: I expect the when the new value assigned to l then l2 will change as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check Ned Batcheleder's excellent explanation - [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

the long story short, initially list1 and list2 refer to same object. lists are mutable, so when you append to the object it's still the same object referenced by two different names. After you assign empty list to list1, it refers to different object while list2 still refer to original list

```
>>> list1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list2 = list1
>>> id(list1)
140533230706312
>>> id(list2)
140533230706312
>>> list1.append(4)
>>> list1
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list2
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> id(list1)
140533230706312
>>> id(list2)
140533230706312
>>> list1 = []
>>> id(list1)
140533231045704
>>> id(list2)
140533230706312
>>> list2
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```